# Web Scraping Android Application

Tags: android, web-scraping

As part of my final year project, I'm designing an Android application that needs to do some web scraping.  I don't have any experience with this, so am wondering if anyone knows of any good links/tutorials they would like to share.

EDIT: I'm trying to have the app sign into a site and upload details from the phone to the site.

Comment: What is your definition of web scraping? Is it to scrape information directly from HTML source? Or do you really mean a web crawler? Other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for extracting and manipulating HTML data.

Answer (score 2):

Some more details on what you actually want to acheive would be usefull so people can try to point you in the right direction.

Here is one link from google: [Using Xpath and HTML in Android](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/)

Another link from SO: [Fastest way to scrape a HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971155/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scrape-html-webpage-in-android)

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to have the app sign into a site and upload details from the phone to the site.