# xPath on AndroidwebView

Tags: android, html, xpath, webview

I am working on Android `webView`. I have an `xPath` with me and a `webView`. I want to evaluate the `xPath` on the `webPage` in the `webView`. Can anyone please help me with this? I tried the following code, but it didn't work.

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "xpath expression";
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, webView, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

and I also saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971155/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scrape-html-webpage-in-android). But I don't know how he got `html`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `JavaScriptInterface` class as a `Callback` for retrieving `HTML` content from `WebView`. Here [a sample tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20160516164926/http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/).

Comment: thanks for that. what shoul be the type of variable html? I need to evaluate my xpath on it

Comment: I tried the same way from the link u gvae. but getting the following warning


10-18 17:16:51.939: WARN/InputManagerService(67): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4069c180 
this happens when i try to communicate from js to android