# How can I parse webpage content in Android

Tags: android

I have a webpage that I know the contents of (standard look)
I am trying to parse the webpage in my android device so that I can extract certain information (say phone number). I have the URL.
How can I achieve this in Android? Any suggestion to how I can start or a quick example of doing so?
Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [HTMLCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) or [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/), for more information please check this example: http://blog.andrewpearson.org/2010/07/android-html-parsing.html

Also check out this StackOverflow question: [What is the fastest way to scrape HTML webpage in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971155/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scrape-html-webpage-in-android)