# Fetch Data from website to android app

Tags: android, xml, json

Hi i new to android development i want to develop an android app for website which does not have JSON or XML API for providing data is it possible to get the data from the **website as it updates** to my android app please

Help even the slightest hint will be appreciated.i have Googled this but i didn't got proper answer

Comment: You can't get or access any data from server without any json, sml, rest or any other api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You will need the following components:

- The website won't notify you when something changes. Thus, you have to **poll** the website frequently to find out if something changed.
- Since the website offers no API, you will have to download the HTML and **parse** it.

Using these keywords in your search, you should find lots of material on StackOverflow, e.g.

- [Android Polling from a Server periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11779132/87698)
- [How can I parse webpage content in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9695972/87698)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an app for a website, then you will have to get that website and parse it and display the results however you want. A good example for this can be found under the [Spring for Android's Github page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android-samples)

If the website you intend to parse is already available in the Spring social package, then the above examples will already provide you with the solution (or with something very close to it). But keep in mind that you can also do the same thing without Spring but you will have to parse the data manually.