# Is it possible to get HTML content in Android?

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to get HTML content in Android and remove what I don't need from it?
For example I want to get the name of the top movies in IMDB(http://www.imdb.com/chart/top), now is it possible just to get the names without anything else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does IMDB provide an API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api)

Comment: @nrofis Actually I don't want for IMDB, I want for a similar site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if your target site has an API. If it does, fine!
If it doesn't, you can read details from the HTML itself, it's called Web Scraping.
You can find how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971155/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scrape-html-webpage-in-android).

**EDIT:**
I see you've found an API and it working with XML. You can find how to work with XML in android [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html).