# JSoup not showing all the html in Java (td and tr tags missing)

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I'm having trouble getting all the html code under the  tags. Here is my current code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971155/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scrape-html-webpage-in-android").get();
Elements desc = document.select("tr");

System.out.println(desc.toString());
```

It's for that question, and I'm trying to get the text from the question's description. But I'm getting not getting certain tr or td tags like the ones for the question. Here is td tag I'm trying to get:

> ```
> <td class="postcell">
> ```

Under that tag is the actual post. Now when I print out what I'm actually getting, I'm getting a ton of empty td tags and some comments, but not the actual post.

```
 <tr id="comment-37956942" class="comment ">
 <td>
 <table>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td class=" comment-score"> &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
  <td> &nbsp; </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table> </td>
 <td class="comment-text">
<div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
 <span class="comment-copy">You shouldn't parse HTML with regexes: <a   href="http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/" rel="nofollow">blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way</a></span> –&nbsp;
 ﹕    <a href="/users/25612/motob%c3%b3i" title="469 reputation" class="comment-user">motobói</a>
```

And it keeps on going with empty td and tr tags. I can't find the actual question. Anyone know why this is happening?

Essentially, I just want the text from the question's post, and I don't know how to get it, so it would be nice if someone could show me how to get the text.

Comment: It sounds like it is loaded dynamically. If is that the case you won't be able to get the content with jsoup. Besides that the `get()` method returns a `Document` so you don't need to create another `Document`.

Comment: Yeah I fixed the code with the document stuff, I was just testing stuff out. Though, what do you mean by it loading dynamically? I'm still getting some comments inside of the html. I just want to know how I can get the text from the question in the link.

Comment: Try this selector `td.postcell` (like you said), and if you get nothing is because the post is being loaded dynamically (e.g ajax call).

Comment: Yeah I tried that earlier, it gave me nothing. What do you mean by "it is being loaded dynamically"? Does that mean I have no way of getting the post? Because if I use a 'div' selector, then the post shows up (along with everything else so it is hard to filter it down to the post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jsoup is a parser. That means that it can't execute any javascript code, that could generate html. When you encounter this problem the only way to retrieve that content is through a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser), that includes a javascript engine. A popular library is [selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).

In order to determine if the content you are trying to parse is generated in the server (static content) or in the client (dynamic content-javascript generated) you can do the following:

1. Visit the page you want to parse
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

The steps above will open a new tab that contains the content that jsoup receives. If the content you need is not there, then it's generated by javascript.

Follow the steps and search for the content. If it's there, but jsoup still has problems, then most probably the case is that the site considers you a bot or a mobile device. Try setting the `userAgent` of a desktop browser and see what happens.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971155/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scrape-html-webpage-in-android").userAgent("USER_AGENT_HERE").get();
```

Most importantly, when the site exposes and API for the users to extract information programmatically then it's better to just use that. 
[Stackoverflow has an API available](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)

Comment: Thanks, I saw by doing CTRL+U that the post was not generated by javascript. I took your suggestion and used the useragent, the one I used I got from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581655/jsoup-useragent-how-to-set-it-right (third answer with the .execute and other stuff). Now I can see the post cell.