# How to get specific data from a website and show it in my app?

Tags: android, html, json, parsing, web-scraping

Maybe similar question was already asked but I couldn't find answer that would work for me. I want to get from website (https://www.fcbarcelona.com/football/first-team/schedule) only this informations (in red square) : date, time and name of clubs. I looked that there is a way to get informations with json parsing but I don't know how would that work here. Im new to this and don't even know what to search for, I don't need written code just help on how to do that.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

We can get certain values from webview in android by loading the data in webview , You should need some knowledge in html and javascript.

1. Open the website in browser and right click on the page click inspect element or inspect(chrome)
2. find the id/class/tag that you need from that webpage

In Android

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
    "document.getElementsByClassName('match__main__date__dmy')[0].style.color = 'red'; " +  
    "})()");

webview1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("document.getElementsByTagName('match__main__date__dmy')[0].onsubmit = function () {");
    sb.append(",// create your Json ");
    sb.append("};");

   //parse the json to get your desired output
}
});
```

Use the above code(need to change according to your needs)

[image]

Comment: Do you know if I can maybe use firebase database to acces that data. I can manualy put dates and times to databse and acces it from app? Is that one posibility ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the website doesn't provide some API to get those data.

Therefore the way i would suggest is [HTML Scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). This can be done with Java on the Android.

**First Option**

- Use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library. An HTML parser

Example

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements matchDate = doc.select("p".first); //<p> tag
```

**Second Option**

- Use build in tools like [DOM Parser](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) - Reference  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081073/6792992)

I would personally use jsoup since it's more convenient and easy to use. Of course all that requires a basic knowledge of HTML.

Comment: Do you know if I can maybe use firebase database to acces that data. I can manualy put dates and times to databse and acces it from app? Is that one posibility ?